# how to load an entity completely?

Tags: hibernate

I'm using hibernate with spring boot and faced a problem loading an entity. Because if it runs without debug it goes fine. But if I'm debugging and I open the entity (in the debug window) and then hibernate says (Collecting data...), then everything runs fine and responce comes back quickly.

`org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@2fb5d2f1 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag to java.util.List`

could it be because he didn't load the collections completely? And why am I not getting LazyInitializationException?

Comment: This exception can be caused by LazyInitializationException, can you check your log stack to see who causes this?

Comment: @LinhVu I checked full stack trace firstly, so it's not the reason.

Comment: So weird, so let put your debug point after you exit the @transactional method. If this time you get the above exception, pretty sure that your supposition's right.